# Too many fields defined Access DB Oledb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

Hello my problem is this. When I want to update a data record in my Access database I get the error "Too many fields defined". I create the update string myself.

```
string query = "";
query = "UPDATE Example SET Dateiname = '" + listofObjects[i].fileName
                                                              + "', Dateidatum = '" + listofObjects[i].fileDate
                                                              + "', DateidatumString = '" + listofObjects[i].dateTimeString
                                                              + "', VolleStundeString = '" + listofObjects[i].fullHourString
                                                              + "', Datum = '" + listofObjects[i].date
                                                              + "', Transportiert = '" + listofObjects[i].transported
                                                              + "', Erfasst = '" + listofObjects[i].detected
                                                              + "', Transportnummer = '" + listofObjects[i].transportNum
                                                              + "', Bearbeitet = '" + listofObjects[i].processed
                                                              + "', SequenceNumber = '" + listofObjects[i].sequenceNum
                                                              + "', File_Delete = '" + listofObjects[i].file_Delete + "'";



                    for (int e = 0; e < anzahl; e++)
                    {
                        query += ", WERT_" + (e + 1) + " = '" + listofObjects[i].LineValueObjects[e].value
                                                             + "', WERT_" + (e + 1) + "_O = '" + listofObjects[i].LineValueObjects[e].value_o
                                                             + "', WERT_" + (e + 1) + "_Q = '" + listofObjects[i].LineValueObjects[e].value_q
                                                             + "', WERT_" + (e + 1) + "_Q_VS = '" + listofObjects[i].LineValueObjects[e].value_q_full
                                                             + "', WERT_" + (e + 1) + "_VS = '" + listofObjects[i].LineValueObjects[e].value_full + "'";
                    }
                    
                    query += " WHERE Dateiname = '" + listofObjects[i].fileName + "'";

                    dbm.updateDB(query);
```

I haven't found a suitable answer yet

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/too-many-fields-defined-error

Is not this. 

Cause
The internal column count that Microsoft Access uses to track the number of fields in the table has reached 255, even though you may have fewer than 255 fields in the table. This can happen because Access does not change the internal column count when you delete a field. Access also creates a new field (increasing the internal column count by 1) for every field whose properties you modify.

Comment: ah okay does that mean if I update the entry more often, then it counts it all the time and is thus over 255 at some point, even if I only edit 40 columns?

Comment: I understand that even if you edit 40 columns, when you try to add new fields it counts +1. So for 1 row it will be maybe 3 or 4 or 5 or 6...

Comment: I understood it to mean that access has the limit at 255 fields. But if you do an update with 180 fields, it does not work, because access for each field that is updated takes a field extra for the updated value. In other words, you only have 127 fields which can be updated in an update statement.

Comment: yes. It is. So you solved it I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/too-many-fields-defined-error#:%7E:text=too%20many%20fields.-,Cause,when%20you%20delete%20a%20field.)
Is not this?

**Cause the internal column count that Microsoft Access uses to track the number of fields in the table has reached 255, even though you may have fewer than 255 fields in the table. This can happen because Access does not change the internal column count when you delete a field. Access also creates a new field (increasing the internal column count by 1) for every field whose properties you modify.**